# SVG Image in JavaFX 2.2

Tags: svg, javafx, batik

I am new to JavaFX 2.2 and as of now I couldn't find a way to display SVG Images in my JavaFX 2.2 application. I took a look at Batik, but it didn't do the trick for me as it converts to `BufferedImages` and not to `javafx.ImageView`.

Is there any way to display an SVG image in an JavaFX application? Or can you at least export an SVG image from JavaFX? Does the function `Node.snapshot()` help there in any way?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

> Is there any way to display an SVG image in an JavaFX application?

Here are some options:

1. Create a [WebView](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html) and [load](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html#load(java.lang.String)) the svg image into the WebView's WebEngine.
2. The [e(fx)clipse](http://efxclipse.org/) project includes an [svg to fxml converter](https://github.com/tomsontom/e-fx-clipse/tree/master/at.bestsolution.efxclipse.formats.svg) (link now dead :().
3. This [NetBeans plugin](http://jayskills.com/blog/2012/06/06/new-netbeans-plugin-svg-2-fxml/) also converts svg to fxml (link now dead :().
4. You can use an awt based library like [Batik](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/) or [svgsalamander](http://svgsalamander.java.net/) and convert the resultant BufferedImage to a JavaFX Image.
5. JavaFX 2.2 natively includes support for some minimal [SVGPath](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/shape/SVGPath.html) strings (not the full SVG spec).
6. You could write a convertor which renders the svg using JavaFX Canvas [GraphicsContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/canvas/GraphicsContext.html) commands.
7. [FranzXaver](https://github.com/afester/FranzXaver) provides an SVGLoader, whose usage is demonstrated in the answer to: [Load SVG file in a Button on JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40078276/load-svg-file-in-a-button-on-javafx)
8. https://github.com/hervegirod/fxsvgimage

   - This library allows to convert a SVG file to a JavaFX Node tree or an Image.
   - Note that contrary to other existing libraries, this library has no external dependencies (including Batik)

> Or can you at least export an SVG image from javafx?

This feature sounds like a JavaFX SceneGraph to svg converter.  While it is theoretically possible, I am not aware that anybody has created such a tool yet.

> Does the function Node.snapshot() help there in any way?

[Node.snapshot()](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#snapshot(javafx.scene.SnapshotParameters,%20javafx.scene.image.WritableImage)) will not help with exporting an svg image from a JavaFX scene graph as svg is a vector based format and a node snapshot is a bit mapped format.

> I took a look at Batik, but it didn't do the trick for me as it converts to BufferedImages and not to javafx.ImageView.

You can easily convert between awt BufferedImages and javafx images using [SwingFXUtils](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/embed/swing/SwingFXUtils.html).

> In terms of performance - which way would you recommend?

For complex svg's, rather than rendering from fxml, you will probably get better performance rendering to a bitmapped image or canvas graphics context.  This is because your scene graph will end up a lot simpler, with far less nodes - which means that the javafx runtime will have a lot less work to do.  For simple svgs (< 1000 nodes generated), it probably won't matter too much.

> Is converting an SVG to an FXML about creating instances of javafx.scene.shape.SVGPath?

Partially.  The full [SVG specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/) covers much more ground than the basic shapes.  In addition gradients, effects, animations, etc can be performed by an SVG.  So if the source SVG image includes those additional items, then they also need to be converted to FXML (as best they can be, there will be some aspects of SVG such as scripting which would be hard to translate to FXML).

My guess is that the size and complexity of the SVG specification is one of the reasons why no direct support for the full SVG image system is currently included in the JavaFX core API and, instead, only limited similar functionality such as SVGPath is offered.  Implementing SVG natively in the JavaFX core API would have been high cost for relatively little reward when compared to other desirable items.

> If that is the case, wouldn't #2 (and #3) and #5 be just the same?

No.  The NetBeans and Eclipse tools referenced in #2 and #3 were more functional than just the SVGPath facilities mentioned in #5, as those tools converted additional aspects of the the SVG specification to FXML equivalents (e.g. gradients, effects and transforms).

Comment: Thanks for youre detailed answer! In terms of performance - which way would you recommend? Converting them all to fxml?

Comment: Thanks! I'd like to vote your answer up, but I don't have the reputattion to do that. Sorry!

Comment: @jewelsea Is converting an SVG to an FXML about creating instances of `javafx.scene.shape.SVGPath`?  If that is the case, wouldn't #2 (and #3) and #5 be just the same? Or are you mentioning a different `SVGPath` in #5? (Edit: Apparently it's the same as I see the link.  So I 'd rather ask if the ones in #2 and #3 are not about `javafx.scene.shape.SVGPath`.) I'm looking at this example: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/usander/e-fx-clipse/master/at.bestsolution.efxclipse.formats.svg/samples/application-exit.fxml

Comment: https://github.com/hervegirod/fxsvgimage you should add this library as it doesn't use Batik,

Comment: @trilogy thanks, I added a link to the hervegirod fxsvgimage to the list of options.

Answer (score 28):

I used the transcoder class above to create a little project on github that adds SVG support to JavaFX (JavaFX 8 though): [javafxsvg](https://github.com/codecentric/javafxsvg)

After calling

```
SvgImageLoaderFactory.install();
```

you can use SVG images anywhere in your Java code or CSS just like any other supported image type.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it depends on batik which is broken and shows no sign of being fixed any time soon.

Answer (score 11):

#### JavaFX + Batik + Custom Transcoder

Since I've nowhere found a complete example of using Batik in conjunction with JavaFX, I am providing a complete solution below.

Note that I removed exception handling (e.g. for the `TranscoderException`) for brevity.
You can access the **full code** here: https://gist.github.com/ComFreek/b0684ac324c815232556

1. In order to convert a SVG file with Batik to a `BufferedImage`, you have to implement a custom transcoder:

   ```
   /**
    * Many thanks to bb-generation for sharing this code!
    * @author bb-generation
    * @link http://bbgen.net/blog/2011/06/java-svg-to-bufferedimage/
    * @link In case the link above is still down: https://web.archive.org/web/20131215231214/http://bbgen.net/blog/2011/06/java-svg-to-bufferedimage/
    */

   public class BufferedImageTranscoder extends ImageTranscoder {

       private BufferedImage img = null;

       @Override
       public BufferedImage createImage(int width, int height) {
           BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
           return bi;
       }

       @Override
       public void writeImage(BufferedImage img, TranscoderOutput to) throws TranscoderException {
           this.img = img;
       }

       public BufferedImage getBufferedImage() {
           return img;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Use the transcoder to generate a `BufferedImage` object:

   ```
   BufferedImageTranscoder trans = new BufferedImageTranscoder();

   // file may be an InputStream.
   // Consult Batik's documentation for more possibilities!
   TranscoderInput transIn = new TranscoderInput(file);

   trans.transcode(transIn, null);
   ```
3. Convert the `BufferedImage` object to an `Image` object (from JavaFX):

   ```
   // Use WritableImage if you want to further modify the image (by using a PixelWriter)
   Image img = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(trans.getBufferedImage(), null);
   ```
4. Finally assign the previously received object to your `ImageView`:

   ```
   imgView.setImage(img);
   ```

Comment: Batik has been broken on Java9+ for a few years now and the maintainers don't seem too interested in fixing it so if you need to run on a JRE released in the last 5 years it is going to be a waste of time pursuing this approach. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BATIK-1260 for details. Combined with the kitchen sink non-optional dependencies which shade common api jars - eg jython - I wouldn't recommend using Batik at all in production code.

Comment: @Dave https://github.com/hervegirod/fxsvgimage doesn't use Batik

Comment: @trilogy - this answer isn't talking about fxsvgimage

Comment: I know I was just letting you know

Answer (score 2):

I did not want to use a library which needed batik, so I developed a small library with no dependencies here: https://github.com/hervegirod/fxsvgimage

There are method to produce a JavaFX Node tree, and others to produce an Image.

The main class is also named `SVGLoader`, but this library is self-contained. Of course, it might not support the full extend of Batik.

Comment: Used this thanks.  How do you set the width of an SVG image like "setPrefWidth(50)" ? I don't want to convert to an java.Image because then when you scale your DPI on your display, the image becomes rasterized. I was able to get the width by using an SVG with the correct size, but what If I wasn't?

Comment: You can use the LoaderParameter class and set the scale or the width. For example: LoaderParameters params = new LoaderParameters();
      params.width = 50;
      SVGImage image = SVGLoader.load(<my svg>, params);

Comment: Thanks, will give it a go. When will you be on maven?

Comment: That's a highly requested feature I know. For the moment, it's possible through jitpack, I will try to add proper Maven support before next week :)

Answer (score -1):

Using WebView. Below is a working example of loading SVG, with CSS animation support:

- controller class SplashController.java:

  ```
  public class SplashController implements Initializable {
        @FXML
        private StackPane rootPane;
        @FXML private WebView webView; 
        private WebEngine webEngine; 
            public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
             webEngine = webView.getEngine();
              URL url1 = getClass().getResource("/android_switch_string.svg");
              webEngine.load(url1.toExternalForm());
            }
    }
  ```
- resource file splash_svg.fxml:

  ```
  < StackPane fx:id="rootPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="360.0" prefWidth="508.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="diagnosticsWin.SplashController">
          <children>
            <WebView fx:id="webView" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
          </children>
        </StackPane>
  ```

Full code description https://www.ap-impulse.com/splash-screen-and-javafx-statya-106/

Project https://github.com/nik137/Diagnostics